# Free Graded Commutative Algebra on a Graded Vector Space

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a graded vector space, thought of as a collection $\{ V^n \}_{n \ge 0}$ of vector spaces. Let $V_{odd} = \bigoplus_{n \text{ odd}} V^n$ and $V_{even} = \bigoplus_{n \text{ even}} V^n$. I am trying to show that there is a functor
$$
\Lambda \colon \mathsf{GVec} \longrightarrow \mathsf{CGAlg}
$$
between graded vector spaces, and commutative graded algebras which is left adjoint to the forgetful functor - i.e. $\Lambda V$ should be the free commutative graded algebra on $V$.

One way to define this is $\Lambda V = E( V_{odd} ) \otimes S(V_{even} )$ where $E$ denotes the exterior algebra and $S$ the symmetric algebra.
However I am having trouble showing that it is commutative.

We can think of the exterior and symmetric algebras as polynomial algebras on basis elements of each of $V_{odd}$, $V_{even}$ respectively, subject to some relations. Let $\underline{x} \otimes \underline{y}, \underline{z} \otimes \underline{w}$ be elements in $\Lambda V \otimes \Lambda V$, where the underline means a monic monomial. Multiplying these gives
$$
(\underline{x} \otimes \underline{y} ) \cdot (\underline{z} \otimes \underline{w}) = (-1)^{|\underline{y}| | \underline{z}|} \underline{x} \underline{z} \otimes \underline{y} \underline{w} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
by definition of the tensor product of graded algebras. However if we apply the braid to the element $\underline{x} \otimes \underline{y}\otimes \underline{z} \otimes \underline{w}$ this gives
$$
(-1)^{| \underline{x} \otimes \underline{y}||\underline{z}  \otimes \underline{w}| } \underline{z} \otimes \underline{w} \otimes \underline{x} \otimes \underline{y} = (-1)^{(| \underline{x}| +  |\underline{y}|)(|\underline{z}\ + |\underline{w}| )} \underline{z} \otimes \underline{w} \otimes \underline{x} \otimes \underline{y}
$$
then multiply we get
$$
(-1)^{(| \underline{x}| +  |\underline{y}|)(|\underline{z}| + |\underline{w}| )} (-1)^{|\underline{w}| |\underline{x}|}\underline{z} \underline{x}\otimes \underline{w} \underline{y}
$$
We can swap $\underline w$ and $\underline y$ since they live in the symmetric algebra, and can swap $\underline z$ and $\underline x$ after multiplying by $(-1)^{| \underline x| |\underline z | }$ so the above expression simplifies to
$$
(-1)^{|\underline y| |\underline z| + |\underline y| |\underline w |} \underline{x} \underline{z}\otimes \underline{y} \underline{w}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
$$

(1) and (2) should be the same. What have I done wrong?

EDIT: Just to be clear I am trying to show that $\mu \sigma = \mu$ where $\sigma$ in $\mathsf{GVec}$ is the braiding $a \otimes b \mapsto (-1)^{|a||b|}b \otimes a$ and $\mu$ is the multiplication.

Comment: To be clear -- I take it "commutative" here is meant in the graded sense of that word, where odd degree things are supposed to anticommute with each other?

Comment: What I mean by a commutative graded algebra is a commutative monoid/algebra object in the symmetric monoidal category of graded vector spaces $\mathsf{GVec}$ where the symmetry isomorphism is given by $a \otimes b \mapsto (-1)^{|a| |b| } b \otimes a$. So that  is precisely what you said, I think.

Comment: Hm -- surely when making $E(V_{odd})$ and $S(V_{even})$, you want to preserve the degrees that things had in the original?  Then the problem goes away; the two things you're comparing both simplify to $xz\otimes yw$ (ignoring underlines), since the exponent on the $-1$ is even in both cases.  Or is there some reason it's not as simple as that?

Comment: yes but $\underline y$ could be written as $y_1y_2y_3$ for example, where each $y_i$ is some basis element of $V_{even}$. That is still an element of odd degree in the symmetric algebra.

Comment: No my point is that you define degree so that it isn't.  You ignore that notion of degree and use the notion of degree that occurs if you give each element of $V_{odd}$ or $V_{even}$ the degree it already had.

Comment: OK I see what you are saying - so you don't just put on the canonical grading on the tensor product of two graded algebras, you invent a new grading that uses the evenness and oddness. Will give this a think through